# Set colnames in data frame based upon vector of names in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `output` with dim() characteristics of 563 (y) variables and 2947 observations (x). Columns 1 - 2 are subject #s and test labels whereas 3-563 are the names of the variable observations.

I have a separate data frame `df-vars` containing 561 variable names. How can I set the column names of my original data frame `output` to the 561 variable names if `df-vars`?

`df-vars` looks like this:

```
    V1  V2
1   1   tBodyAcc-mean()-X
2   2   tBodyAcc-mean()-Y
3   3   tBodyAcc-mean()-Z
4   4   tBodyAcc-std()-X
5   5   tBodyAcc-std()-Y
6   6   tBodyAcc-std()-Z
7   7   tBodyAcc-mad()-X
```

Comment: `names(output)[-(1:2)] <- dfvars[[1]]`?

Comment: Nope that just renamed the columns 1:563 as opposed to the names within the df-vars.

Comment: If I drop the [-(1:2] then it will rename all of my columns with the names in df-vars, which is nice. However, the offset (begin @ col #3) doesn't work. So it recycles the names at the end and it's not accurate.

Comment: Wrong tag: you want to use [tag:data.frame]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the column names of my original df (output) to the 561 variable names (df-vars)

You can set a subset of the column names of `output` to the appropriate names within `df-vars`, for instance if `df-vars` contains the column names in column 2:

```
colnames(output)[3:563] = as.character(df-vars[,2]);
```